# Gorm 2, Golang, Auto migrate table with foreign key

Tags: go, foreign-keys, migration, go-gorm

```golang
import  "gorm.io/gorm"

type Object struct {
    gorm.Model
    ObjectId  string      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ListItems []ListItem `gorm:"foreignKey:ObjectId;references:ObjectId"`
}

type ListItem struct {
    gorm.Model
    ObjectId   string           
    Data string
}
```

I define two objects, then try to auto migrate following [the guide](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Constraints)

```golang
db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&Object{}, "ListItems")
db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&Object{}, "fk_object_list_items")
db.AutoMigrate(&Object{}, &ListItem{})
```

Fails with

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "blobber_ch
```

I can't find any examples for this. I tried different permutations of everything.
I suspect the foreign key in the migration does not match the foreign key in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary_key for Object struct as gorm.Model already have one:

```
    ID        uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
```

You have two otpions : not to use gorm.Model or get rid of ObjectId primary_key and clean **references:ObjectId** from gorm annotation.

```
type Object struct {
    gorm.Model
    ObjectId  string
    ListItems []ListItem `gorm:"foreignKey:ObjectId;"`
}

type ListItem struct {
    gorm.Model
    ObjectId string
    Data     string
}

db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&Object{}, "ListItems")
db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&Object{}, "fk_object_list_items")
db.AutoMigrate(&Object{}, &ListItem{})
```